# How to implement that SQL query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am having a hard time implementing the following SQL query in mysql.

i am trying to find For every supplier that only supplies green parts, print the name of the supplier and the total  number of parts that she supplies.

my SQL query is

```
SELECT S.sname , count(*)
FROM Suppliers S,Parts P,Catalog C
WHERE P.pid = C.pid AND C.sid = S.sid
GROUP BY S.sname , S.sid
HAVING EVERY (P.color = 'green')
```

any suggestions on how to implement that in mysql will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using the `NOT EXISTS` construct is the easiest way to go:

```
SELECT s.sname, COUNT(*)
FROM   suppliers s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   parts p
                   JOIN   catalog c ON p.pid = c.pid
                   WHERE  c.sid = s.side AND p.color != 'green')
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `HAVING` if you are using the aggregate function itself to compare.
Use also `JOIN` not the old school multiple-table comma separated because
that could have unintended consequence.

```
SELECT S.sname , count(*) as TotalParts
FROM Suppliers S
INNER JOIN Catalog C
ON S.sid = C.sid
INNER JOIN Parts P
ON P.pid = C.pid
WHERE   P.color = 'green'
GROUP BY S.sname
```

Comment: If a supplier has some red parts, for example, you will still get a count for that supplier.